# Is there a general way to avoid exceptions when editing XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, exception

I have a XAML page with a `DataContext` configured for a view model:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <current:OrdersViewModel  />
</Window.DataContext>
```

The constructor for `OrdersViewModel` attempts to connect to a repository via a factory.

```
public OrdersViewModel()
{
    using (var repos = RepositoryFactory.Create()) // Throws exception - not configured
    {
        // Get data
    }
}
```

The factory is configured in the constructor for my App.xaml.cs.

However, when I'm visually editing my main XAML page, it attempts to construct an `OrdersViewModel`  object without calling the `App` constructor. Thus an exception is thrown from the `OrdersViewModel`  constructor, causing a warning (or sometimes an error) in my XAML editor.

I can get rid of this by simply wrapping my constructor code in a try/catch block.

```
public OrdersViewModel()
{
    try
    {
        using (var repos = RepositoryFactory.Create()) // Throws exception - not configured
        {
            // Get data
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

However, this seems inelegant. Exception handling is there for when the code is running, not when it's being edited. And if I get an exception when I'm running, I don't want it ignored like this. And as my program gets more complex, I need more an more of these.

So my question is, is there a way to get the XAML editor to generally ignore exceptions? Or a way to stop it even attempting to create the DataContext object while editing?

(Note: The question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304547/how-to-force-visual-studio-2010-to-ignore-a-wpf-xaml-declared-datacontext-at-des), but there's no entirely general purpose answer.)

Comment: I'm not sure this older answer addresses my question any more than the one I referenced. These tell me how to do mocking, which, as my question states, I already do. What I'd like to do is switch off the editor's attempts to create the view-model entirely, or to simply make it ignore exceptions coming from the view-model.

Comment: The other question gets you part of the way. The other thing you may need is d:IsDesignTimeCreatable. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472228/how-to-use-ddesigninstance-with-types-that-dont-have-default-constructor